# VirtualBox and linux without gui - how to change screen resolution?

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-server

**VirtualBox conf:**

```
Host: Windows 10
Guest: Ubuntu Server (no gui)
```

When I run machine output is in very low resolution
and line length is limited.

**I tried:**

- change scale => result: just bigger letters
- change view => result same as above
- change gfx => no changes

How to make line longer and increase resolution?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `xrandr --size 1366x768` (or whatever resolution you want) in the Guest OS (i.e. Ubuntu)?

Comment: It is distribution without gui.